# Debugging WinRT component with Cordova

Tags: cordova, windows-runtime, cordova-plugins

I have an app in development using Cordova and some WinRT components that would register a background task. I am able to run the WinRT components in my js code via a custom cordova plugin that I have developed, as I some test code and it is returning correctly.

The WinRT component is setup as another project, and build dir is output to the src directory of the cordova plugin.

I tried place a debug breakpoint in source code of the winRT component, and expect that when I call the WinRT component, it should break, but it doesn't.

Any one know what is wrong?